# regex with optional character/class/group doesn't seem to work

Tags: regex, karate, optional-values

Regex operator ? for optional character/class/group seems to fail.
Karate version: 0.9.9.RC1

I tried to match a phone number with optional leading + sign against these, but fails to match

- `<number>#regex \+?\d{6,11}</number>`
- `<number>#regex (\+)?\d{6,11}</number>`
- `<number>#regex [\+]?\d{6,11}</number>`

Here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#the-karate-object at `karate.extract(text, regex, group)`, I read that `regex` follows the Java regex rules, so I checked my regex here to be sure I did not make a mistake (there are too many flavors of "standard" regexes):

https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html
Here, all the above regexes work as expected for phone numbers with or without leading +.

Of course there is the alternative to use an alternative, but it is clumsy.
This works within a karate match: `<number>#regex \+\d{6,11}|\d{6,11}</number>`

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: not sure. feel free to investigate and submit a PR or at least an explanation of how to fix it. else this is not on my list of priorities

Comment: Since the regex is fine, is it the problem with 1) text input? 2) final regex representation? Like, is `+` a plus symbol or some entity?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: while comparing two xml fragments, I noticed #number does not work, since the text that is the content of an element is seen as a String. For regex: the + needs to be escaped one for literal char, else it is taken as Kleene + (one or more)

Comment: For now my workaround is #regex \+{0,1}\d{6,11}

Comment: BTW, I had similar problems like above if I replace ? by *, so 
<number>#regex \+*\d{6,11}</number>
also fails